# How to cross compile a .c file for Openwrt?

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack, openwrt

I am trying to cross compile a .c file for Openwrt. I downloaded Openwrt and added my file in package directory and created Makefile for it but while compiling it is skipping. I don't know what is wrong

This the Makefile :

*

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk
include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/kernel.mk
PKG_NAME:=gav
PKG_VERSION:=1
PKG_RELEASE:=1
include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk
define Package/gav
  SECTION:=utils
  CATEGORY:=Base system
  TITLE:=gaurav
endef
define Package/gav/description
 This package contains an utility useful to upgrade from other firmware or 
 older OpenWrt releases.
endef
define Build/Prepare
    mkdir -p $(PKG_BUILD_DIR/)
    $(CP) ./src/* $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/
endef
define Package/gav/install
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/sbin
    $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/gav $(1)/sbin/
endef
$(eval $(call Buildpackage,gav))
```

*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the toolchain skips your Makefile entirely, most probably you haven't run **make menuconfig**.

So generally the steps are:

1. Place your openWRT Makefile into openwrt/package/name folder
2. run **make menuconfig**
3. in the pop-up dialog choose the package you want to compile by putting either an **M** or * next to it.
4. run **make package/name/compile**
5. you'll find the .ipk file in openwrt/bin/

Comment: Thanks, it worked !! for a normal helloworld program. Now i m trying to cross-compile hostapd package but i am getting error fatal "error: netlink/genl/genl.h: No such file or directory" . I have installed libnl-dev but still getting the same error.

Comment: Now it has something to do with the gcc compiler. I cannot tell what's wrong but I guess the compiler simply doesn't find genl.h. I guess you have a 'hostapd project' with its own Unix-Makefile generated by some IDE (e.g. NetBeans)? Then most probably you need to include path netlink/genl/genl.h in your project in the IDE. Let me know if it's not clear. P.S. I am sure there is a hostapd package for OpenWRT. Are you sure you need to compile it again?

Comment: I downloaded hostapd and made some changes in it now i want my hostapd to be compiled not the inbuilt hostapd package. I am using ubuntu. I have added my hostapd in openwrt/package/ directory and enabled it in make menuconfig. I don't know why it is not taking genl.h path.

Comment: look at **hostapd-x.x/src**. You'll see a Makefile. It tells the gcc compiler what sub directories to compile and how. Each subdirectory contains its own Makefile too. I don't know what changes you made to the hostapd package but you need to tell the gcc compiler about them, that is, edit the Makefiles according to your changes. P.S. For my own large projects (only having a bunch of .c and .h files) I use Netbeans IDE which can create a Makefile for me automatically. In your case, however, I think it's best to modify the Makefiles by hand.

Comment: Most probably all you have to do is to add `genl` to the first line of the Makefile located at \hostapd-x.x\src. But note you'll need another Makefile in \hostapd-x.x\src\genl which you can copy from any other subdirectory (e.g. \hostapd-x.x\src\ap). Let me know how it goes